# "I will eat apples upto 10 hours" Does "upto" mean "with in ten hours" or "for the period/duration" of ten hours" or it could mean both?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

"I will eat apples upto 10 hours". Does "upto" mean "with in ten hours" or "for the period/duration of ten hours" or it could mean both?

Comment: This expression is not idiomatic, and I think ungrammatical.  "Upto" is not a word of standard English I assume you mean "up to".  Even so the phrase "up to ten hours" does not work and is incorrect grammar.  Would you say "I'll eat apples ten hours"?  Are you quoting, or did you write this yourself?

Comment: @James K. I write it myself.

Comment: Then there's no real way of answering this question.  It doesn't mean either, it doesn't mean anything much.  -- This question is an "apple" question.  You are asking about an artificial example, (and often these examples are about apples).  But what is the real problem you want to solve.  Are you in a situation now in which you want to use "up to"?  What is the real situation?  What do you really want to communicated?

Comment: In fact, you should probably be using either a continuous, or a perfect tense, and probably use "for up to 10 hours"

Comment: "I love apples. I could eat apples *all day, every day.*" is something a native speaker might conceivably say. But "I could eat apples *for up to 10 hours*" seems entirely idiosyncratic and arbitrary.  You should use examples that provide far more context for the utterance.

Comment: @ James K. Yes this is what i wanted to know. I guess people occassionaly forget to put "for" when they mean to say "for up to" am i right here?

Comment: I wouldn't have thought it was a common error.

Comment: @Kate Bunting. Could please, simply your comment for me for better understanding.

Comment: You asked "Am I right (in saying that people occasionally leave out _for_)?" They may do so _very_ occasionally, but I don't think it's a common error.

Comment: @Kate Bunting. Thank you.

Comment: There are times when **for** can be left out. *We'll have to climb 10 hours non-stop if we want to reach the summit before dark.*  or *He stayed holed up in that cabin six months before going into town for rations.*  *We can climb up to 10 hours non-stop if we need to.* *You can stay holed up in that cabin up to six months before you'll need to go into town for supplies. The pantry is well stocked.*

Answer (score 3):

As multiple comments have noted, the sentence is not grammatically correct. As such, the question is meaningless.

I can not know for sure what you meant, but here are a few candidates that would be grammatically correct:

1. I will eat apples for up to ten hours.
2. I will eat up to ten apples for hours.
3. I will eat lots of yummy apples.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes this is what i wanted to know. I guess people occassionaly forget to put "for" when they mean to say "for up to" am i right here?

Comment: People occasionally make all kind of mistakes.  This one isn't particularly common, and not something to be copied.

Comment: @BilalZafar I have not seen that happen often, but yes, that is a candidate for what might have happened.